# How would you dim a container/panel like a modal Msg?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm trying to implement a view that requires a response from the server to update itself, so I'd like to 'dim' the container and show a spinner while it's asynchronously loading information from the server and then 'undim' when it's finished.

I've seen the same effect from the background of a Msg/Panel and would like to implement exactly the same thing with a spinner in the middle.

Comment: there are many ways to do this. How are communicating with server? Can you show that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the regular extjs [loadMask](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.LoadMask), let us know if you need help using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how to create a modal window in Sencha touch, then this is the best example.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?122382-Can-I-have-a-quot-popup-quot-panel-opened-on-clicking-a-button

You can mask the panel using loadmask configuration